# How can I generalize this function to `n` terms?

Tags: matlab, function, vectorization, anonymous-function

I'd like to create a function that adds several gaussian terms of various width over some specified region:

```
G(a,b,x) = a_1 exp(- b_1 x^2) + a_2 exp(- b_2 x^2) + ... a_N exp(-b_N x^2)
```

I'd like this function to output an array of length `x`, summing over the terms of parameters `a,b` provided, something like:

```
x = linspace(-2,2,1000);
N_gauss = @(a,b) a(:).*exp(-b(:)*x.^2);
```

This example actually works if `a,b` have only a single value, but when they become vectors it no longer works (I suppose Matlab doesn't know what should be added, multiplied or remain a vector).  Is this even possible?

Comment: So `a` and `b` are vectors of the same length and for each value in `x`, you want to apply the equation using the **same** values in `a` and `b`?

Comment: yes!  if I understand you correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this purely by matrix multiplication.  Let's tackle the problem slowly and work our way up.  You first need to form products of the elements of the vector `b` and scalar values stored in `x`. First create a 2D matrix of values where each row corresponds to the product-wise values between an element in `b` and an element in `x`.  The element `(i,j)` in this matrix corresponds to the product of the i<sup>th</sup> element in `x` with the j<sup>th</sup> element in `b`.

You can achieve this by using the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).  Make `x` a column vector and `b` a row vector, then perform the multiplication.  Also, make sure you square each of the `x` terms as seen in your equation.

```
term1 = (x(:).^2)*b(:).';
```

Now you can apply the exponential operator and ensure you place a negative in the exponent so you can build the right side of each term (i.e. `exp(- b_i x^2)`):

```
term2 = exp(-term1);
```

The last thing you need to do is multiply each of the values in the 2D matrix with the right coefficient from the `a` vector.  You can do this by enforcing that `a` be a column vector and performing matrix-vector multiplication.

```
out = term2*a(:);
```

Matrix-vector multiplication is the dot product between the column vector `a` with each row in the 2D matrix we created before.  This exactly corresponds to the summation of your equation for each value in `x`.  As such, this achieves the Gaussian summation for each value in `x` and places this into a `n x 1` vector where `n` is the total number of elements in `x`.  Putting this all together gives us:

```
out = exp(-(x(:).^2)*b(:).')*a(:);
```

To finally abstract this into an anonymous function, do:

```
N_gauss = @(a,b,x) exp(-(x(:).^2)*b(:).')*a(:);
```

This function takes in the vectors `a`, `b` and `x` as per your problem.

Comment: @anon0909 my pleasure. I've added more comments so you can understand what's going on. Let me know.

Comment: Actually I can do this with pure matrix multiplication. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: @anon0909 revised. purely using matrix multiplication.